# F# Units of measure - 'lifting' values to float<something>

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

When importing numbers from a csv file, I need to convert them to floats with unit.

Currently I do this with an inline function:

```
data |> List.map float |> List.map (fun n -> n * 1.0<m>)
```

But I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this - or do I have to create my own 'units' module with conversion functions?

What would be really nice would be something like this, but I doubt it's possible...

```
data |> List.map float |> List.map lift<m>
```

*This is the opposite of my previous question ([How to generically remove F# Units of measure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412459/how-to-generically-remove-f-units-of-measure)).*

UPDATE: For homemade units, I've tried this, which works ok:

```
[<Measure>]
type km = 
    static member lift (v:float) = v * 1.0<km>

data |> List.map float |> List.map km.lift
```

or, following the question in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419521/f-units-of-measure-lifting-values-to-floatsomething#424111)

```
data |> List.map (float >> km.lift)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like units of measure can't be type parameters for the moment (no idea if this will change). So the shortest way to write this is:

```
data |> List.map float |> List.map ((*) 1.0<m>)
```

EDIT

See also now `FloatWithMeasure` here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806527(VS.100).aspx

Comment: Given that units are purely compile-time, it doesn't seem likely to change.

Comment: FloatWithMeasure just saved me from a lot of hair pulling, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you have to map twice? What's wrong with this:

```
data |> List.map (fun x -> (float x) * 1.0<m>)
```

Comment: Yeah, I could, have done so, but the idea was that my lift function would be generally applicable to floats. But see corrected code in UPDATE in question.