# F# 'unbox float x' vs. 'unbox int x' weird compilation result

Tags: f#, type-inference, units-of-measurement

This came up while I looked at the following question: [F# Unit of Measure, Casting without losing the measure type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894250/f-unit-of-measure-casting-without-losing-the-measure-type/21797834#21797834)
Please note that I am not trying to use this unbox code, I just discovered some weird behavior while answering the question.

Why does the following code work

```
let intToFloat (x:int<'u>) : float<'u> = unbox float x
intToFloat 1<second>
```

while this yields a *System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'float32ToFloat@86-6' to type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[System.Single,System.Double]'.*?

```
let float32ToFloat (x:float32<'u>) : float<'u> = unbox float x
float32ToFloat 1.0f<second>
```

If I put parantheses around the `(float x)` the code works as expected, so I assume it must be some expression evaluation/type inference rule. What exactly is going on here and why are the parantheses needed in the second case?

Comment: Tomas's answer explains the error, but as a side-note, `unbox` is not the best way to do this. You should use `LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<'u>`, which translates to a no-op in .NET bytecode, whereas `unbox` adds some runtime type checking which is not necessary in this case.

Comment: @Tarmil, I was aware of that. Thanks for confirming that `FloatWithMeasure` is a better option though (see my answer to the linked question). Would you mind adding/confirm this over there as well?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your post in the question you linked. So we pretty much said the same thing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subtle thing in your code snippets is `unbox float x` - the compiler treats this as  `(unbox float) x`. As a result the two functions are actually treated like this:

```
let intToFloat (x:int<'u>) : float<'u> = 
  let f = unbox float in f x

let float32ToFloat (x:float32<'u>) : float<'u> = 
  let f = unbox float in f x
```

So, you are taking the `float` function, casting it (unsafely) to a function of another type and then calling it. The type is `int<'u> -> float<'u>` in the first case and `float32<'u> -> float<'u>` in the second case.

I think the first one works because when the compiler sees the `float` function (without any type annotations), it defaults to `int -> float` and, since units of measure are erased at runtime, this can be converted to `int<'u> -> float<'u>` (but not to the second type - because you are performing unsafe cast).

So, the main problem is wrong parentheses in your implementation (which leads to a really subtle issue). I think you probably wanted something like this:

```
let intToFloat (x:int<'u>) : float<'u> = unbox (float x)
let float32ToFloat (x:float32<'u>) : float<'u> = unbox (float32 x)
```