# Using F# Units of Measure with System.Numerics.Vector<T>

Tags: .net, f#, vectorization, simd, units-of-measurement

I struggle using F# units of measure in combination with the `System.Numerics.Vector<'T>` type. Let's have a look at a toy problem: Assume we have an array `xs` of type `float<m>[]` and for some reason we wanted to square all its components, resulting in an array of type `float<m^2>[]`. That works perfectly well with scalar code:

```
xs |> Array.map (fun x -> x * x) // float<m^2>[]
```

Now suppose we wanted to vectorize this operation by performing the multiplication in `System.Numerics.Vector<float>.Count`-sized chunks using SIMD, for instance like so:

```
open System.Numerics
let simdWidth = Vector<float>.Count
// fill with dummy data
let xs = Array.init (simdWidth * 10) (fun i -> float i * 1.0<m>)
// array to store the results
let rs: float<m^2> array = Array.zeroCreate (xs |> Array.length)
// number of SIMD operations required
let chunks = (xs |> Array.length) / simdWidth
// for simplicity, assume xs.Length % simdWidth = 0
for i = 0 to chunks - 1 do
    let v = Vector<_>(xs, i * simdWidth) // Vector<float<m>>, containing xs.[i .. i+simdWidth-1]
    let u = v * v                        // Vector<float<m>>; expected: Vector<float<m^2>>
    u.CopyTo(rs, i * simdWidth)          // units mismatch
```

I believe I understand *why* this happens: How could the F# compiler know, what `System.Numerics.Vector<'T>.op_Multiply` does and what arithmetic rules apply? It could literally be any operation. So how should it be able to deduce the correct units?

**The question is**: What the best way to make this work? How can we tell the compiler which rules apply?

**Attempt 1**: Remove all units of measure information from `xs` and add it back later on:

```
// remove all UoM from all arrays
let xsWoM = Array.map (fun x -> x / 1.0<m>) xs
// ...
// perform computation using xsWoM etc.
// ...
// add back units again
let xs = Array.map (fun x -> x * 1.0<m>) xsWoM
```

Problems: Performs unnecessary computations and/or copy operations, defeats the purpose of vectorizing the code for performance reasons. Also, largely defeats the purpose of using UoM to begin with.

**Attempt 2**: Use inline IL to change the return type of `Vector<'T>.op_Multiply`:

```
// reinterpret x to be of type 'b
let inline retype (x: 'a) : 'b = (# "" x: 'b #)
let inline (.*.) (u: Vector<float<'m>>) (v: Vector<float<'m>>): Vector<float<'m^2>> = u * v |> retype
// ...
let u = v .*. v // asserts type Vector<float<m^2>>
```

Problems: Doesn't require any additional operations, but uses a deprecated feature (inline IL) and isn't fully generic (only with respect to the unit of measure).

**Does anyone have a better solution for this***?

*Note that the above example really is a toy problem to demonstrate the general issue. The real program solves a much more complicate initial value problem, involving many kinds of physical quantities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a solution, that meets most of my requirements (it seems). It is inspired by [TheInnerLight's ideas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34577544/96583) (wrapping `Vector<'T>`), but also adds a wrapper (called `ScalarField`) for the underlying array data type. This way we can track the units, while underneath we only handle raw data and can use the not unit-aware `System.Numerics.Vector` APIs.

A simplified, bare-bones quick and dirty implementation would look like this:

```
// units-aware wrapper for System.Numerics.Vector<'T>
type PackedScalars<[<Measure>] 'm> = struct
    val public Data: Vector<float>
    new (d: Vector<float>) = {Data = d}
    static member inline (*) (u: PackedScalars<'m1>, v: PackedScalars<'m2>) = u.Data * v.Data |> PackedScalars<'m1*'m2>
end

// unit-ware type, wrapping a raw array for easy stream processing
type ScalarField<[<Measure>] 'm> = struct
    val public Data: float[]
    member self.Item with inline get i                = LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<'m> self.Data.[i]
                     and  inline set i (v: float<'m>) = self.Data.[i] <- (float v)
    member self.Packed 
           with inline get i                        = Vector<float>(self.Data, i) |> PackedScalars<'m>
           and  inline set i (v: PackedScalars<'m>) = v.Data.CopyTo(self.Data, i)
    new (d: float[]) = {Data = d}
    new (count: int) = {Data = Array.zeroCreate count}
end
```

We can now use both data structures to solve the sample problem in a *relatively* elegant, efficient way:

```
let xs = Array.init (simdWidth * 10) float |> ScalarField<m>    
let mutable rs = Array.zeroCreate (xs.Data |> Array.length) |> ScalarField<m^2>
let chunks = (xs.Data |> Array.length) / simdWidth
for i = 0 to chunks - 1 do
    let j = i * simdWidth
    let v = xs.Packed(j) // PackedScalars<m>
    let u = v * v        // PackedScalars<m^2>
    rs.Packed(j) <- u
```

On top, it might be useful to re-implement usual array operations for the unit-aware `ScalarField` wrapper, e.g.

```
[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.ModuleSuffix)>]
module ScalarField =
    let map f (sf: ScalarField<_>) =
        let mutable res = Array.zeroCreate sf.Data.Length |> ScalarField
        for i = 0 to sf.Data.Length do
           res.[i] <- f sf.[i]
        res
```

etc.

Drawbacks: Not generic with respect to the underlying numeric type (`float`), because there is no generic replacement for `floatWithMeasure`. To make it generic, we have to implement a third wrapper `Scalar` the also wraps the underlying primitive:

```
type Scalar<'a, [<Measure>] 'm> = struct
    val public Data: 'a
    new (d: 'a) = {Data = d}
end

type PackedScalars<'a, [<Measure>] 'm 
            when 'a: (new: unit -> 'a) 
            and  'a: struct 
            and  'a :> System.ValueType> = struct
    val public Data: Vector<'a>
    new (d: Vector<'a>) = {Data = d}
    static member inline (*) (u: PackedScalars<'a, 'm1>, v: PackedScalars<'a, 'm2>) = u.Data * v.Data |> PackedScalars<'a, 'm1*'m2>
end

type ScalarField<'a, [<Measure>] 'm
            when 'a: (new: unit -> 'a) 
            and  'a: struct 
            and  'a :> System.ValueType> = struct
    val public Data: 'a[]
    member self.Item with inline get i                    = Scalar<'a, 'm>(self.Data.[i])
                     and  inline set i (v: Scalar<'a,'m>) = self.Data.[i] <- v.Data
    member self.Packed 
           with inline get i                          = Vector<'a>(self.Data, i) |> PackedScalars<_,'m>
           and  inline set i (v: PackedScalars<_,'m>) = v.Data.CopyTo(self.Data, i)
    new (d:'a[]) = {Data = d}
    new (count: int) = {Data = Array.zeroCreate count}
end
```

... meaning that we basically track the units not by using "refinement" types like `float<'m>`, but solely through wrapper types with a secondary type/units argument.

I'm still hoping someone comes up with a better idea, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is fine with figuring out how to apply unit rules for multiplication, the problem here is that you have a wrapped type.  In your first example, when you write `xs |> Array.map (fun x -> x * x)`, you're describing the multiplication in terms of the elements of the array rather than on the array directly.

When you have a `Vector<float<m>>`, the units are attached to the `float` rather than the `Vector` so when you try and multiply `Vector`s, the compiler won't treat that type as if it has any units.

Given the methods exposed by the class, I don't think there is an easy workaround using the `Vector<'T>` directly but there are options for wrapping the type.

Something like this could give you a unit-friendly vector:

```
type VectorWithUnits<'a, [<Measure>]'b> = 
    |VectorWithUnits of Vector<'a>

    static member inline (*) (a : VectorWithUnits<'a0, 'b0>, b : VectorWithUnits<'a0, 'b1>) 
        : VectorWithUnits<'a0, 'b0*'b1> =
        match a, b with
        |VectorWithUnits a, VectorWithUnits b -> VectorWithUnits <| a * b
```

In this case, the units are attached to the vector and multiplying vectors works as expected with the correct unit behaviour.

The problem is that now we can have separate and distinct unit of measure annotations on the `Vector<'T>` and on the `float` itself.

You can the turn an array of a specific type with units of measure into a set of the `Vector`s using:

```
let toFloatVectors (array : float<'m>[]) : VectorWithUnits<float,'m>[]  =
    let arrs = array |> Array.chunkBySize (Vector<float>.Count)
    arrs |> Array.map (Array.map (float) >> Vector >> VectorWithUnits)
```

and back:

```
let fromFloatVectors (vectors : VectorWithUnits<float,'m>[]) : float<'m>[] =
    let arr = Array.zeroCreate<float> (Array.length vectors)
    vectors |> Array.iteri (fun i uVec ->
        match uVec with
        |VectorWithUnits vec -> vec.CopyTo arr)
    arr |> Array.map (LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure<'m>)
```

**A hacky alternative:**

If you give up the generic type `'T` you can make a `float Vector` behave properly through some fairly horrible boxing and runtime casting.  This abuses the fact that units of measure are a compile time construct that no longer exist at runtime.

```
type FloatVectorWithUnits<[<Measure>]'b> = 
    |FloatVectorWithUnits of Vector<float<'b>>

    static member ( * ) (a : FloatVectorWithUnits<'b0>, b : FloatVectorWithUnits<'b1>) =
        match a, b with
        |FloatVectorWithUnits a, FloatVectorWithUnits b ->
            let c, d = box a :?> Vector<float<'b0*'b1>>, box b :?> Vector<float<'b0*'b1>>
            c * d |> FloatVectorWithUnits
```

Comment: Hm, I tried the `FloatVectorWithUnits`, but the measures for the `(*)` operator get automatically constrained to "1" (dimensionless, signature `FloatVectorWithUnits<1> * FloatVectorWithUnits<1> -> FloatVectorWithUnits<1>`). Also, `VectorWithUnits` requires additional explicit type constraints, but otherwise seems to work. I thought about wrapping the type as well, but I didn't know you could just assert/force certain rules for the measure parameters. Interesting.

Comment: @Frank Curious.  I had some problems installing the `Vector<'T>` type from `System.Numerics.Vectors` - I read that the `Vector<'T>` type had actually been removed from the stable versions so I had to test this code in a slightly roundabout way but I am not getting the same constraint to "1".   I wonder if this could be related to different F# versions, will try to investigate.

Comment: @Frank I'm very sorry, I think the second example was a no-go.  It worked in my slightly dodgy workaround for those installation issues but I don't think it's going to work for you unless you can find a way to strip the unit of measure annotations and re-add them explicitly in the arithmetic function definitions which I know you wanted to avoid.  Hopefully the first approach will still be helpful...

Comment: Yeah, there's still something wrong with the NuGet package, at least for some combinations of .NET framework/F# and Numerics.Vector versions (see also https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3103). It works for me with .NET 4.5.2, F# 4.0 and Vectors 4.1.1-beta-23516.

Comment: @Frank So, there is a way to recreate the second example using some runtime casting, which I guess is similar to your original inline IL approach.

Comment: Functionally, yes. The difference is, that runtime boxing/unboxing/casting is expensive (compared to a plain `mulpd`/`vmulpd` instruction). I'm afraid I can't use that in an inner, performance-critical loop.

Comment: Another problem with your first idea: How do I create a `VectorWithUnits<float, 'm>` from an existing `float<'m>[]`? The `Vector<_>(values: 'a[], index: int)` constructor has to create a `Vector<float<'m>>` instead of a `Vector<float>` given the `float<'m>[]` as the `values` parameter...

Comment: And how would I copy the result to the `float<'m^2>[]` if it was possible to drop the unit of measure when creating the inner `Vector<float>` instance?

Comment: @Frank I've added some sample functions to do the conversion.  Again, we can do it by defining functions that operate on a specific type but we're seriously restricted by the type system.  Units of measure on wrapped types are pretty hard to work with without `map`.

Comment: @Frank For further material, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404027/strip-unit-of-measure-from-array?lq=1.  I'm not sure if the compiler is capable of optimising any of these runtime conversions because, in theory, it should be possible for it to be free at runtime.